# Why does Perl compile diagnostics.pm if I have no diagnostics in my code?

Tags: perl, devel-nytprof

When I was looking at the output of [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf) v4 for a [CGI program](http://perl-hunting.blogspot.de/2010/01/use-develnytprof-with-cgi-and-apache.html), I came across the `diagnostics.pm` in the report *Source Code Files — ordered by exclusive time then name*.

[image: diagnostics.pm]

First I didn't understand why that would be in the production code. I dug deeper through the report and found out that it was called by `main::BEGIN@17`. That, in turn, is the following line:

```
# spent 34µs (26+8) within main::BEGIN@15 which was called: # once (26µs+8µs) by main::RUNTIME at line 15
use strict;
# spent 34µs making 1 call to main::BEGIN@15 # spent 8µs making 1 call to strict::import

# spent 36µs (17+19) within main::BEGIN@16 which was called: # once (17µs+19µs) by main::RUNTIME at line 16
use warnings;

# spent 36µs making 1 call to main::BEGIN@16 # spent 19µs making 1 call to warnings::import

# spent 292ms (171+121) within main::BEGIN@17 which was called: # once (171ms+121ms) by main::RUNTIME at line 17
no diagnostics;
# spent 292ms making 1 call to main::BEGIN@17

# spent 135µs (27+108) within main::BEGIN@18 which was called: # once (27µs+108µs) by main::RUNTIME at line 18
use Carp qw( carp croak );
```

So this seems to be the culprit. I removed the `no diagnostics` line, and the call was gone, effectively saving about 300ms of time.

Here's what [perldoc `use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) says about the `no` keyword:

> There's a corresponding no declaration that unimports meanings
>   imported by use, i.e., it calls unimport Module LIST instead of
>   import. It behaves just as import does with VERSION, an omitted or
>   empty LIST, or no unimport method being found.
>
> ```
> no integer;
> no strict 'refs';
> no warnings;
> ```

So here's my actual question: **Am I correct in assuming that if I call `no diagnostics`, it is actually loaded before it is `unimport`ed?**

Is the call to `no diagnostics` similar to this piece of code?

```
BEGIN {
  require diagnostics.pm;
  diagnostics->unimport;
}
```

In consequence, is it a bad idea to just unimport stuff that has never been imported, because that actually loads it first?

Comment: Before anyone points that out: I'm not trying to optimize anything (yet), I'm merely trying to understand what is being called at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that if I call `no diagnostics`, it is actually loaded before it is unimported?

Yes. Its indeed full equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
  require diagnostics;
  diagnostics->unimport;
}
```

So `no module` command actually loads and compiles the module; including executing the code which is not in any **sub**, in BEGIN block etc; same for all dependencies of given module(for every **use**/ **require** inside).

Comment: In the "ordinary" case, the module is already loaded because you `use`d it somewhere, so the `require` is a no-op and only the `unimport` matters. But yes, assuming the module hasn't been `require`d at any previous point, `no` will do so.