# Calculating date time in perl

Tags: perl

am new to perl am trying to do a script which can check

last seen / days / hours and minutes

i have made some try.

but i need help to make it function well

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use DateTime;

my $Datetime = DateTime->now;

my $date = $Datetime->ymd;   
my $time = $Datetime->hms;

$Seen_time = "11:50:02";
$Seen_day = "2022-01-12";

if ($Seen_time eq $time) {
    print "His Online\n";
}

elsif  ($Seen_time ne $time) {
    
    # calculate how many minutes has passed from current time and seen time
    print "He was online 3 minutes or hours back\n";
}

elsif  ($Seen_day)  {
    
    # calculate days from date 
    print "he was online 2 days back\n";
}
else {
      print "we are going to moon soon\n";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19483585/1466640 may be useful

Comment: its not helpful, as the date and time modules are different, the time and date output is different from Datetime module

Comment: See also [Time::Ago](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Ago) and [DateTime::Format::Human::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Human::Duration)

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to compare dates with string equality. There is lots to read in the documentation for [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

Comment: I second all the suggestions above and note other than missing a 'my' before $Seen_time and  $Seen_day the code compiles fine, so please clarify exactly what output you expect..

Comment: where is comment is where i want to fix, the code has no problem but there only 1 step which was done $Seen_time eq $time but others are just comment to clarify on wat i want

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rough implementation using DateTime::Format::Human::Duration
[https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Human::Duration](http://%20https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Human::Duration)
as Håkon Hægland suggested, you will need to fine tune the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Human::Duration;

my $Datetime = DateTime->now;

my $Seen_time = "11:50:02";
my $Seen_day = "2022-01-12";
# You probably need to take the above and get it in a DateTime object this is just for the example:
my $seen = DateTime->new(year => 2022, day => 12, month => 1, hour => 11, minute => 50, second => 2);

#you could use the DateTime->compare method to compare two DateTime objects. The semantics are compatible with Perl's sort function; 
#it returns -1 if $seen < $Datetime etc.

my $cmp = DateTime->compare( $seen, $Datetime );

if (!$cmp) {
    print "He is Online\n";
}

elsif  ($cmp == -1) {
    my $d = DateTime::Duration->new();
    my $span = DateTime::Format::Human::Duration->new();
    my $dur = $Datetime - $seen;
    # You can fine tune this output to just me hours or whatever:
    print "He was online " . $span->format_duration($dur) .  " ago \n";
}


else {
      print "We are going to moon soon\n";
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want `use diagnostics` in your code unless you explain what it's for, and only during development. [It adds a lot of load time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566980/1331451).

Comment: Yep good point, I consider anything I post here 'during development' though. The op will obviously need to incorporate this into a larger program.