# Date and time calculation

Tags: perl

I have made a update on my question at [Calculating date time in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698196/calculating-date-time-in-perl),

this is another try. the only problem i have is evaluating or comparing to have good output.

i want to output only. lets say if the minutes less than 60 or equal to 60 print minutes when others values like hours days and months are equal to 0

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;

my $Datetime = DateTime->now;

my $date = $Datetime->mdy;   
my $time = $Datetime->hms;

my $Seen = '01/10/2022 05:22:03';
my $CurrentDateTime = "$date $time";

my $SeenDateTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $Seen ) );
my $CurrentDate_AndTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $CurrentDateTime ) );

my $diff = $CurrentDate_AndTime->subtract_datetime( $SeenDateTime );

$Min = $diff->in_units('minutes');
$Hour = $diff->in_units('hours');
$Day = $diff->in_units('days');
$Month = $diff->in_units('months');

print "Minutes: " . $diff->in_units('minutes') . "\n";
print "Hours " . $diff->in_units('hours') . "\n";
print "Days: " . $diff->in_units('days') . "\n";
print "Month " . $diff->in_units('months') . "\n";

########## PROBLEM IS DOWN HERE  ###############

if ($Seen eq $CurrentDateTime) {
print "His Online Now\n";
}

elsif ($Min <= 60) {
    print "Seen $Min Minutes Ago\n";
}

elsif ($Hour <= 24) {
    print "Seen $Hour Hours Ago\n";
}

elsif ($Day <= 30) {
    print "Seen $Day Days Ago\n";
}

elsif ($Month <= 12) {
    print "Seen $Month Month Ago\n";
}

else {
    print  "Welcome come back from moon\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 2 months and 5 minutes will show as 5 minutes.

It's because you're starting with the smallest unit when you should be starting with the largest unit.

```perl
my ( $years, $months, $weeks, $days, $hours, $minutes ) =
   $dur->in_units(qw( years months weeks days hours minutes ));

if    ( $years  >=  1 ) { say "Welcome back from the moon!";   }
elsif ( $months >   1 ) { say "Last seen $months months ago."; }
elsif ( $months ==  1 ) { say "Last seen 1 month ago";         }
elsif ( $weeks  >   1 ) { say "Last seen $weeks weeks ago";    }
elsif ( $weeks  ==  1 ) { say "Last seen 1 week ago";          }
elsif ( $days   >   1 ) { say "Last seen $days ago";           }
elsif ( $days   ==  1 ) { say "Last seen 1 day ago";           }
...
```